# Oracle SQL - selecting only records that appear in each month of a year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set of monthly billing records, but I want to filter out newer accounts that don't have a 12 month history and I'm not really sure how to approach this.

I was thinking about something using row number = 12 but not sure how to do that at the level of detail for each account and not the entire dataset. Also saw a post here about having count(date) = 12, but I don't think I'm executing that correctly.

Comment: Does "12 month history" mean that there can be any number of records but oldest record is at least 12 months old? Or does it mean that there must be a record in at least 12 prior distinct months?

Comment: Hi, add table schema and some data samples. As text, not images. That will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You use the windowing capability of aggregate functions, specifying a PARTITION BY.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT x.*,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY account_no) cnt
          FROM monthly_billing_records x)
 WHERE cnt >= 12
```

What Oracle will do is generate that query block results, then make a second internal pass over those results and do a GROUP BY whatever your PARTITION BY column list is, compute the COUNT(*), and join that back to the results on the PARTITION BY columns. That way you can summarize multiple rows and report the result on each individual row. It can do a lot more complicated stuff than that, so read up on PARTITION BY, ROWS BETWEEN , etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `id` for accounts with 12 months of data (the current month and the preceding 11 months) then you can `GROUP BY` the account's `id` and `COUNT` the `DISTINCT` dates within each month (`WHERE` the dates are within the expected time period) and then to only get those with a full 12 month history you can use a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(dt, 'MM')) AS num_months
FROM   table_name
WHERE  dt <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  +1)
AND    dt >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -11)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(dt, 'MM')) = 12;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, dt) AS
  -- Every month for the current month and past 11 months
  SELECT 1, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1 - LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
UNION ALL
  -- 12 months of historical data but not for the current month
  SELECT 2, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 0 - LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
UNION ALL
  -- Only 4 months of data
  SELECT 3, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1 - LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NUM_MONTHS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UMw0of8P)